# CSS Selecting the next element that follows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to target the next p block in the following code. While the FOO highlights in yellow, Foo 2 is not highlighting in red, even though my CSS uses the adjacent sibling syntax (+). What could be going wrong here?

```
<style>
p span.test { background-color: yellow; }
p span.test + p { background-color: red !important; }
</style>


<p>
    <span class="test">Foo</span>
</p>

<p>Foo 2</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

The sibling selector actually is working correctly there. The issue is that the first rule `p span.test { background-color: yellow; }` is targeting **"any `span` with class `test` that is inside a `p`"**. It's the `span` that is being made yellow, not the `p`.

The second `p` is not a sibling of the span -- int is only a sibling of the other `p`. So the rule does not apply to it.

Unfortunately, [there is no CSS "parent" selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), so you can't easily reverse this. Instead, you would have to put a class on at least one of the `p`'s, like below:

```css
p span.test { background-color: yellow; }
p.first + p { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<p class="first">
    <span class="test">Foo</span>
</p>

<p>Foo 2</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. While technically your answer is correct, I cannot modify the original code so the first p has to remain without a class. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly without seeing the whole document. In this toy example, you could use the [`nth-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector. You could also definitely achieve this with javascript. I don't know the exact jQuery phrase offhand but I think it would be easy to do something like "select all `span`s inside of `p`s, get their parents, and then get their parents' first siblings."

Comment: Ah yes -- the nth-child helped, as I was able to find an element higher up that let me target the right paragraph!

Answer (score -1):

The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.

In your code, the two `<p>` tags are children of the same parent. but the `<span>` is a child of `<p>` tag. So, if we consider the "test" class and next `<p>` tag, they are not child elements of the same parent. So, that is the reason why your code is not working.

The correct syntax is:

```
former_element + target_element { style properties }
```

Therefore your code should be changed as follows:

```
    <style>
        p span.test { background-color: yellow; }
        p + p { background-color: red; }
    </style>
```

This works fine.